# Is there anyway to stretch a block wrapped in an inline-flex to match parent div width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: This is the effect that I'm looking for.

[image]

I apologize if the question is worded a bit strangely, but essentially, I have two blocks (one div, one icon) inside a div, which is inside another parent div whose width is dynamically adjusted depending on the width of the text. Basically, I want the icon to remain both inline with the other div, and also be right aligned every time the parent div expands. How can I achieve this?

HTML

```css
.message, .other-message{
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    max-width: 50%;
}


.other-message {

    background-color: gray;
    margin: 10px auto 10px 10px;   
}

.message {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 5px 10px 10px auto;
}
  

.date, .username {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 80%;
}

.date-and-comment-removal{
    display: inline-flex;
}

.date-and-comment-removal > i{
    margin-right: 0;
}

.date-and-comment-removal > i:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.date-and-comment-removal > .date{
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">


<div class="message">nothing much
                <div class="username">nisey</div>
                <div class="date">2021-03-04 3:52 AM</div>
              </div>
            
              <div class="other-message">hey, what's up? Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Felis donec et 
                <div class="username">darienmiller88</div>
                <div class="date-and-comment-removal"> 
                  <div class="date">2021-03-04 3:52 AM</div>                     
                  <i class="bi bi-three-dots-vertical"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
```

The three ellipses I want to expand to the right, and remain right aligned every time the message block expands due to a longer message. What should I add or change?

Comment: Can you add an image of what you want? It's a bit confusing. I did `width: 100%` on the `data-and-comment-removal` element, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Something like [This](https://jsfiddle.net/cztpv6a3/) ?

Comment: @disinfor I added the image of what I wanted, hopefully that clears it up a little bit.

Comment: @ZohirSalak That's close! But I want the date to be aligned to the left, and the icon to be aligned to the right as per the image I just added to my post.

Comment: @DarienMiller Remove `align-self: flex-end;` i added to `.date-and-comment-removal` `margin-right: auto;` you had on `.date-and-comment-removal>.date` already does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `width: 100%` to the `.date-and-comment-removal` and it does what you want.

```css
.message,
.other-message {
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.other-message {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 10px auto 10px 10px;
}

.message {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px 10px 10px auto;
}

.date,
.username {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.date-and-comment-removal {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.date-and-comment-removal>i {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.date-and-comment-removal>i:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.date-and-comment-removal>.date {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">


<div class="message">nothing much
  <div class="username">nisey</div>
  <div class="date">2021-03-04 3:52 AM</div>
</div>

<div class="other-message">hey, what's up? Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Felis donec et
  <div class="username">darienmiller88</div>
  <div class="date-and-comment-removal">
    <div class="date">2021-03-04 3:52 AM</div>
    <i class="bi bi-three-dots-vertical"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```